# Using HttpClient in Blazor server side getting StatusCode 407 AuthenticationRequired

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, blazor

I am trying to access a WebApi from a blazor server side project, having configured HttpClient like below, but I always get:

```
{StatusCode: 407, ReasonPhrase: 'authenticationrequired', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{  Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 11:01:00 GMT  Cache-Control: no-cache  X-Frame-Options: deny  Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive  Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 3851}}
```

```
           services.AddHttpClient<IUsersService, HttpUsersService>(options =>
            {
                options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.example.com/");
                options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            })
                .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(h =>
                    new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
                    });
```

```
private async Task<User> GetUser()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("v1/Users");

    var test = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    var model = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<User[]>(test);

    return model.First();
}
```

Is there a way to get the system's proxy and credentials or what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think that your default credentials are valid for api.example.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you apply this code:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IUsersService, HttpUsersService>(options =>
            {
                options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.example.com/");
                options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            })
                .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(h =>
                    new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
                    });
```

I guess in a Startup class, right ?

OK, since you've mentioned above that you're calling a Web Api end point from a Blazor client-side app, this code should not be used. This code, I guess, creates an HttpClient service from the IHttpClientFactory. This has got nothing to do with the HttpClient service used in Blazor client-side App, which is based on the JavaScript Fetch API.

However, Blazor framework adds the HttpClient service to the DI container by default, and all you've got to do in order to use it is to inject it into your component or class services...

Sample:

```
 @page "/"
    @inject HttpClient Http

    // more code... 

    @code {
        User[] users;

        // more code... 
    private async Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        users = await Http.GetJsonAsync<User[]>("v1/Users");
        return model.First();
    }

    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, how about a server side blazor?

Comment: In Blazor Server, the HttpClient service is not injected by default. You should manually add it  to the DI container, and apply the necessary settings such as the base uri, etc. And here, indeed, you can, actually should, use the IHttpClientFactory. Please, accept my answer if you think it helped you, so that other users trust it...

Comment: @Mihaimyh - when you are using server-side then this answer is of no help at all and you should not have accepted it. It is now unlikely that you will get other help.